# How to test inner functions defined on Stateless Components in React with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I'm using enzyme to test my react components. I have a stateless component that has an inner function. How can i call and test that inner function?

Here is my component:

```
const Btn = (props) => {
  const types = ['link', 'plainLink', 'primary', 'secondary', 'danger', 'info'];

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onClick(event);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} className={classes}>
      <span>{props.children}</span>
    </button>
  );
};
```

I've tried the following, but get an error saying: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor

```
const btnComp = shallow(<Btn />);
btnComp.instance().handleClick();
```

Comment: which line throws the `TypeError`?  the `shallow` or the `instance()`?

Comment: the instance() line

Comment: Generally you don't test private functions. In this specific case you should tigger a click on your button and check whether it did what it should have done.

Answer (score 1):

I usually test this functionality by setting a `sinon.spy` for the event:

```
const click = sinon.spy();
const btnComp = shallow(<Btn onClick={click} />);

btnComp.find('button').simulate('click');

expect(click.called).to.equal(true);
```

Now, you know that the inner function did indeed invoke the `props.onClick` event, which is the most important bit of its work.